# CAMERA permission with Provider in manifest (Android Studio)

Tags: android, performance, android-studio, kotlin, android-layout

I'm implementing scanner and capture image from camera both in different sections of my application,
so I put manifest permission for camera (scanner) and  file provider for capture image in the manifest file,

I put Camera Permission and
provider android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider" android:authorities="com.example.myapplication.fileProvider" android:exported="false" android:grantUriPermissions="true" tools:replace="android:authorities"> <meta-data android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS" android:resource="@xml/file_paths" tools:replace="android:resource"provider
this in manifest file

But I can't use them together as it is throwing error.

is there any other way to do this OR hep me to resolve this.

app is crashing on image capture, when I'm using both, If I remove Camera permission then the Scanner doesn't work. Need help to solve this problem

Comment: It is pretty unclear what you put in manifest.

Comment: I put   Camera Permission and      <provider
            android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider"
            android:authorities="com.example.myapplication.fileProvider"
            android:exported="false"
            android:grantUriPermissions="true"
            tools:replace="android:authorities">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
                android:resource="@xml/file_paths"
                tools:replace="android:resource"/>
        </provider>                        this in manifest file

Comment: I cannot read that from a comment. Please remove and put it in your post readable.

Answer (score 0):

ah, I got d Answer :)
" uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera"
android:required="true"

after adding this in the manifest file, it is working perfectly